# MS Graph getSchedule - response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I´m writing a Node.js application with application permission to access Outlook data of my company via MS Graph. Before I´m digging into programming I´m analyzing all necessary api´s for my application. The following action has to be performed:

I need to get all planned events of a room in my company (response must contain at least **eventId**,  (**start of event** and **organizer** optional) for each entry). I´ve thought I could use the getSchedule() function (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). So the returned scheduleItem collection doesn´t seem to have any eventId property.

My question is, if there is a way to retrieve the id´s of the planned events with this function?
Or do I need to retrieve the events of the calendar via calendarId (via: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get all planned events with eventId?

Answer (score 0):

This topic can be closed. I´ve managed to solve this by using the calendarView API (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)